# securing modals and forms in blade engine laravel

Tags: laravel, security, laravel-blade

how do you secure modal data from exposing in blade template, just wondering how can i protect my Modal form from exposing eg. route,id's etc..when i inspect element or view page source it will reveal the whole form including the id and values of the input below is example, if you have any known article that i could read about this matter appreciate if you share thanks.

**Output From View Page Source**
[image]

**Modal View**

```
@if(count($editor)==1)
<form method="POST" action="{{route('edit.member',$member->pivot->token)}}">
@csrf
@method('PUT')
<div class="modal fade EditMemberModal" id="EditMemberModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Role</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">Current Role</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="role" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">New Role</label>
             </div>
             <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="role">
               <option value="member">Member</option>
               <option value="editor">Editor</option>
             </select>
           </div>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="user" name="user_id">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="group" name="group_id">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>    
@endif
<!--===========================Edit Modal For Members==========================-->
```

Comment: Anything viewable in the web browser will be able to be inspected. Why are you concerned about this?

Comment: Frontend security = No security

Comment: @ Jeremy Harris just making sure for any vulnerability or things that i could enhance in my code.  like exposing the table information would that gave the attacker advantage .

Comment: If you are worried about security on the frontend with it helping an attacked gain knowledge of your backend, you could always alias your input field names to not match your database -- like show "firstName" as input name, and on backend translate that to "user_first_name" for your database. But honestly, focus on sanitizing input and ensuring you are always using prepared statements.

Comment: @Jeremy Harris thanks for the idea, how bout those id's protecting them not to show on the modal is it possible?

Comment: If you need a value on the frontend to send to the backend, it is not possible to prevent somebody from finding it. You *could* encrypt it on the backend, send the encrypted version to the frontend, then decrypt it when submitted back to the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot hide anything that you are using to populate your blade templates.

Once generated by the server and sent to the client, the client can do what they want with your template. This includes changing the names of your input fields, values of hidden input fields & the path of your form action.

What you should focus on is form validation, both on your HTML form but, more importantly, serverside.

Laravel ships with a `Validator` and has the ability to create custom `Request` objects.

Documentation can be found in the Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#form-request-validation)

If you want to go even further, alias your input fields as mentioned by @Jeremy Harris. you can then map them to your database columns in your Controllers.